# auto number counting with macro

Tags: macro

I want to record a macro, which generates a formatted text that includes a number. I want the number to be counted up whenever the macro is invoked.

For example:

```
abc 1 def
abc 2 def
abc 3 def
```

Can I do that?

`Vim`'s version is `7.0`. OS is `CentOS 6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<c-a>` mapping will increment a number in your macro.

```
qqyyp<c-a>q@q
```

The idea is to duplicate the current line (`yy` and `p`) and then increment the newly duplicated line (`<c-a>`).

For more help see:

```
:h q
:h CTRL-A
:h @
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in a function to number a list but taking note that the register may change between sessions something like

```
:let @a=`number you want eg 10`

qp "Record macro
:let @a=@a+1
```

Either

```
:.put a "puts it current line
```

or

```
i   "insert mode
Ctrl-R a  "Control R a will paste register a

q " finish macro
```